# Linux ext2 filesystem why is there a deletion time?

Tags: linux, filesystems

the ext2 inode has a field i_dtime which is the deletion time.

Until today i thought that the deletion of a file removes the inode.

So does anyone know what the sense of this field is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [1]:

The inode is marked as deleted by writing the i_dtime. Special fs tools [2] can analyse the file system and may still restore files by looking at those marked inodes -- until they are actually overwritten.

- [1] http://kris.koehntopp.de/artikel/diplom/node13.html
- [2] http://e2undel.sourceforge.net

Comment: The first link doesn't work. I still don't understand why you need a "deletion time" and not just mark it as unused.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really remove an inode, it's still there in the table. You can only mark it as deleted.

Comment: Why is deletion time needed, can't we just mark it as unused in the bitmap?